# Return relationship set where one relationship exists?

Tags: mysql

[Here's the relevant part of my database on SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03faf/1/0)

Given that set up, I want to write a query that goes "Select th.thing and a list of all tags a thing has where that list of all tags contains tag2".

My expected result set would be:

thing1 | tag1, tag2
thing2 | tag2, tag3

I've tried various joins and grouping method along with `GROUP_CONCAT()`, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

How can I pull my desired result set from the database with 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit hacky because it uses [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), but seems to work ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6274a4/10/0)).

I wouldn't count on it working if any of your tags have a comma in it, since `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't seem to do anything special to escape that comma, so `FIND_IN_SET` will consider it a delimiter.

```
SELECT
  things.thing,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag) AS tags
FROM things
JOIN relationships
  ON things.id = relationships.thing_id
JOIN tags
  ON relationships.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY things.id
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('tag2', GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag));
```

Yields:

```
THING   TAGS
thing1  tag2,tag1
thing2  tag2,tag3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version without the use of semi join nor FIND_IND_SET, 
just straight joins

```
SELECT th.thing, GROUP_CONCAT(ta.tag) as tags
FROM things th
JOIN relationships r
ON   th.id = r.thing_id
JOIN tags ta
ON   ta.id = r.tag_id
JOIN things th2
ON th.id = th2.id
JOIN relationships r2
ON th2.id = r2.thing_id
JOIN tags ta2
ON ta2.id = r2.tag_id
WHERE ta2.tag = 'tag2'
GROUP BY th.id;
```

and demo: --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03faf/21

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of `FIND_IN_SET`, as Waleed Khan suggested, I've prepared a query that uses a `WHERE`-clause. This won't break on tags with a comma, normally...

```
SELECT th.thing, GROUP_CONCAT(ta.tag) as tags
FROM relationships r
INNER JOIN things th ON th.id = r.thing_id
INNER JOIN tags ta ON ta.id = r.tag_id
WHERE th.id IN (SELECT r2.thing_id
                FROM relationships r2
                INNER JOIN tags ta2 ON ta2.id = r2.tag_id
                WHERE ta2.tag = "tag2")
GROUP BY th.id
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03faf/19/0)